# Use of if else in jade

Tags: node.js, pug

I want to use condition for the view if the role of user is 'admin' then li  view will be show to the user else  view will be the different code is below
but condition in not working like this code if i use else if else in the same tag then condition and syntax work otherwise its syntax error

```
 ul.sidebar-menu(data-widget='tree')
 if role == "admin"
  li 
    a(href="/")
      i.fa.fa-dashboard
      span Dashboard
  li.treeview
    a(href='#')
      i.fa.fa-user
      span Courses
      span.pull-right-container
        i.fa.fa-angle-left.pull-right
    ul.treeview-menu
      li
        a(href="/courses")
          i.fa.fa-circle-o
          |  List Of Courses

  li.treeview
    a(href='#')
      i.fa.fa-user
      span Subjects
      span.pull-right-container
        i.fa.fa-angle-left.pull-right
    ul.treeview-menu
      li
        a(href="/subjects")
          i.fa.fa-circle-o
          |  List Of Subjects      

  else
  li.treeview
    a(href='#')
      i.fa.fa-user
      span Teachers
      span.pull-right-container
        i.fa.fa-angle-left.pull-right
    ul.treeview-menu
      li
        a(href="/teachers")
          i.fa.fa-circle-o
          |  List Of Teachers
  li.treeview
    a(href='#')
      i.fa.fa-user
      span Students
      span.pull-right-container
        i.fa.fa-angle-left.pull-right
    ul.treeview-menu
      li
        a(href="/users")
          i.fa.fa-circle-o
          |  List Of Students

.control-sidebar-bg
```

Answer (score 3):

Indentation is very important when writing Pug. Both the `if` and `else` must be at the same indentation level, and their contents must be indented an additional level.

Right now, the indentation looks like this (dashes added for clarity):

```
ul
if role == "admin"
-li 
---a
-else
-li
---a
```

It should look like this (dashes added for clarity):

```
ul
--if role == "admin"
----li
------a
--else
----li
------a
```

Without the dashes, it should look like this:

```
ul
  if role == "admin"
    li
      a
  else
    li
      a
```

Check out the [Pug documentation](https://pugjs.org/language/conditionals.html) for more examples.